# Sub-array division with overlap

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have numpy array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]`. Want to divide in sub-arrays of size 6 with 3 overlap
`[1 2 3 4 5 6] [4 5 6 7 8 9] [7 8 9 10 11 12]` in the above case.

I want to make it generalized.
Say I have a thousand size array. I want to  get sub-arrays of 100 size with 50 overlap.

Also, the overlap size is always half of sub-array size.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> size = 6
>>> overlap = 3
>>> z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> zip(*[z[i:] for i in range(size)])[::overlap]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]
```